# SKAction followPath on a constantly changing path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a CGPath that dynamically changes on every frame and I would like to move a SKSpriteNode on it.

First I tried SKAction followPath but obviously every time the path changes, it doesn't continue the animation.

My other problem with SKAction followPath is, I cannot set the position of the object on the path arbitrarily. For example if you think of a game similar to flight control but the user could control the planes with a slider back and forth on the bezier path.

The option would be to implement some kind of ray casting and check the collision point every frame and this way I could find the y position (x is fine because I move the object forward) but this approach is not really lightweight if I want to use it on every frame.

Do any of you guys have any idea how to implement such a functionality?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Similar to a train on a curvy railway line (that's the path) and the user can go back and forth on the rail by swiping his/her finger. Both the speed and the direction are dynamic based on user interaction.

Comment: CGPath is not the right approach for what you want. Changing direction every frame defeats the concept of a preset path. You will have to go with another approach. You did not include enough information in your question for me to suggest anything else.

Comment: I would like to achieve similar gameplay as the following game (borderline):
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/borderline-life-on-the-line/id924870826?mt=8
In this game the path is generated dynamically but the character goes forward  only at a steady speed. In my game the user can go back too and the speed is not the same all the time, the character can slow down or speed up.

Comment: That's all very nice but seeing that you don't know the source code, don't make any assumptions on how it was done. Also, there's no guarantee that the app was made with SpriteKit. It could have been made with Unity for example.

Comment: I didn't say that it was made with Sprite Kit, I just showed you an example what I would like to achieve. 

I would be surprised if it was impossible to implement similar approach with Sprite Kit or with conventional iOS libraries. I am using Sprite Kit but can integrate other frameworks easily.

Comment: You can create 3 parallel `CGPath`s and have 3 sprites following each of the paths. You then display only one sprite at a time and create an animation that gives the illusion that the character is jumping from one path to another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my CGPath is drawn dynamically and it changes on every frame based on certain user interaction.